# ParserError: Expected token Semicolon

Tags: solidity, remix, truffle-contract, openzeppelin-contracts, create

I got this particular Parser error and can you help me how to fix this issue:while using this code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "../node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol";

contract MyToken is StandardToken {
string public name = "MyTok";
string public symbol = "MTK";
uint8 public decimals = 2;
uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 5000;

function MyToken () public {
    totalSupply__ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    balances[msg.sender]= INITIAL_SUPPLY;
    emit Transfer(0x0,msg.sender,totalSupply_);

    }
}
```

In the line
`emit Transfer(0x0,msg.sender,totalSupply_);`

`localhost/mytoken/contracts/mytoken.sol:14:18: ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen'`
Thanks

Comment: I just updated my code., can you please look at it

Answer (score 1):

I got this to compile with solidity 0.4.18;

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/v1.6.0/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol";

contract MyToken is StandardToken {
    string public name = "MyTok";
    string public symbol = "MTK";
    uint8 public decimals = 2;
    uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 5000;

    event Transfer(address s, address s2, uint amount);

    function MyToken () public {
        totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
        balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
        Transfer(0x0,msg.sender,totalSupply_); // solc 0.4.18 does not have `emit`
    }
}
```

The `emit` keyword is unexpected by *your* compiler. The error is a little misleading. Just drop the word `emit`.

It can be a bad idea to mix up the compiler versions. A higher order concern would be to catch up to a more recent build of Open Zeppelin and a recent compiler. For example:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer shows well how the commonly-used caret-pragma produces unexpected results when the underlying compiler isn't yet at v1. Perhaps you should remove the caret and pin `solc`'s version, like `pragma solidity 0.4.17;`.

Comment: BTW, the availability of `emit` was only officially announced in [`solidity` v0.4.21](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.21).